# Adobe air window with no chrome badly calculates dimensions when maximized

Tags: actionscript, air, google-chrome

When i maximize an air window that has no chrome (no system chrome, no flex chrome but i think it's the same even if only flex chrome is used) a few pixels on all sides go offscreen.

Anyone has a solution for this or knows why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually easiest to set the air window to the size of the monitor, then set your custom UI to the size of the monitor minus a few pixels. That's the only workaround that I've come up with.

The only downside to this approach may be a small rendering performance loss, since the AIR window has to take alpha transparent pictures of everything behind the window, but this likely so minimal that it won't make a difference (I invite someone to benchmark this).

Comment: That's what i did also I haven't noticed any performance issues so if there's any it's not noticeable. (Computer is average to low in performance).